# Can the ternary operator be expanded into if–else statements in C macros?

Tags: c

> Define a macro MAX3 that gives the maximum of three values.

This is what I came up with:

```
#define MAX3(a,b,c) ( ((a) > (b)) && ((a) > (c)) ) ? (a) : ((b) > (c)) ? (b) : (c)
```

This is hard to read. Is there a way to write an equivalent macro with if–else statements?

Comment: Sure there is. Have you tried writing one? What problems did you have?

Comment: be very careful with it. concider: what will `MAX3(x,y,z++)` do?

Comment: @Cody Gray - See my comment for Basile's answer.

Comment: @amit: It will warn the reader that, because `MAX3` is written in all-caps, it's probably a macro, and caution should be exercised in invoking it with arguments that have side effects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Having an expression-like macro with statements inside is not possible in standard C99 language (because in C99 statements and expressions are deeply different, both syntactically and semantically).

However, GCC (and some other compilers with extensions inspired by GCC, e.g. clang) provides a nice extension for that : [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html#Statement-Exprs) (the documentation gives an example related to your question). With that extension you could code something like

```
 #define MAX3(A,B,C) ({ int a=(A); int b=(B); int c=(C); int m; \
     if (a>b) m=a; else m=b;                                    \
     if (c>m) m=c;                                              \
     m; }) /* bad macro */
```

however that still won't work if you use that macro like e.g.

```
 int badex(int x, int y) { 
    int a= x+y; int m= x*y; int d=x-y; 
    return MAX3(a,m,d);
 }
```

I hope you see why it won't work (name clashes e.g. between the `a` inside `badex` and the `a` inside `MAX3` macro). So you need a way to have unique names at every invocation of your macro. Again, GCC provides a nice extension for that, the [`__COUNTER__`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html#Common-Predefined-Macros) macro (expanded to a unique number, counting) used with [concatenation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html#Concatenation) in the preprocessor.

Then you'll code something like

```
 #define MAX3(A,B,C) MAX3_COUNTED((A),(B),(C),__COUNTER__)
 #define MAX3_COUNTED(A,B,C,N)  ({                          \
    int a_##N=(A); int b_##N=(B); int c_##N=(C);            \
    int m_##N;                                              \
    if (a_##N>b_##N) m_##N = a_##N; else m_#N = b_##N;      \
    if (c_##N>m_##N) m_##N=c_##N;                           \
  m_##N; }) /* better example */
```

Then the first invocation of our macro e.g. `MAX3(i++,j++,k++)` might expand to `MAX3_COUNTED((i++),(j++),(k++),1)` which gets expanded into something using `a_1` `b_1` ... and the second  invocation, e.g. `MAX3(a,m,d)` expanded as `MAX3_COUNTED((a),(m),(d),2)` would use `a_2` `b_2`  etc so is better.

And of course, defining a `static inline max3(int a, int b, int c)` function is cleaner (in particular because of side effects: your `MAX3` macro gives naughty effects and results with a call like `MAX3(i++,j++,k++)` etc)

The general lesson about this is that you should when possible avoid macro (preferring inline functions), and when you absolutely need macros take care about name clashes and expansions.

Using GCC invoked as `gcc -C -E` shows you the preprocessed form of your program.

Comment: How do you figure it's "not possible" in C99? You can write macros with `if` statements all day long. What part of the standard does this violate?

Comment: I think Basile means that you can't have an expression 'if ... ' which has a value, the same way the ternary operator does. I also think that was the original question.

Comment: The C language deeply separates expressions from statements: you sadly can't write `int x = while(j<=10) j++;` Some better languages (e.g. Scheme, Ocaml, or even MELT) have only expressions. Rumors are that the very first C compiler (or perhaps only its predecessor B) had only expressions (without statements) but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Basile: "Sadly"? What would be the value assigned to `x` in your example? Especially when then condition and the code block can be arbitrary complex and involve more than one variable? What's the final value of `int x = while ((j<=10) && (i>=5)) { j++; i--; }`?

Comment: @Secure: gcc defines this unambiguously, even though standard C doesn't (see [statement expressions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.2/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html)).  A gcc statement expression is a compound statement enclosed in parentheses.  If the final statement of the compound statement is an expression statement, the whole thing's type and value are that of the final expression; otherwise it's of type `void`.

Comment: @CodyGray: A macro can contain an `if` statement, but if it does it can't be used as an expression (barring use of compiler-specific extensions).

Comment: @Keith, thanks, I remember. Most of the time I ignore any extensions and write fully portable standard C, though. So in 2 or 3 years I will ask this question again. ;)

Comment: @Secure: I might remember having read that in the 1970-s the value of `while` in B (or perhaps the primordial C) was implemented as giving -1 or 0 (I forgot which). Sorry, I don't remember the details. You certainly can have a language with side-effecting expressions. And the very first B or C had only integers as datatype.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably better to do it this way:

```
#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
#define MAX3(a, b, c) MAX(a, MAX(b, c))
```

Or better still, use an inline function rather than resorting to old skool preprocesser abuse:

```
inline int max3(int a, int, int c) { return max(a, max(b, c)); }
```

It's a lot more robust than a macro and just as efficient.

Comment: A macro actually has an advantage over an inline function: it can be used with arguments of any type that has a `>` operator (i.e., any scalar type).  A function, even an inline one, has to declare the types of its arguments.

Comment: Agreed. However, the disadvantage of macros like `MAX3` from original poster is apparent in `MAX3(i++,i++,k++)` invocations. I am actually a quite often of macros, but I really think that they should be documented, and that you should understand how expansion work, which the original poster perhaps didn't, given the formulation of his question.